# Como usar vírgula em Python em vez de ponto

Tags: python

O sistema brasileiro, diferente do sistema americano, utiliza a vírgula para separar decimais, mas como o Python foi feito em um país que utiliza o ponto para separar decimais, os programas, quando usamos a função *print*, usa pontos. Como faço para utilizar vírgula em vez disso?

Como por exemplo: Eu peço para o usuário entrar com seu salário, se ele não tomar o conhecimento da utilização do ponto, o programa irá dar erro e o usuário constatará como BUG, então, como faço para mudar isso?

Comment: faz um replace da entrada dele trocando o ponto por virgula

Comment: Como???????????

Answer (score 8):

### Abordagem, rápida e suja - "str.replace":

As facilidades de manipulação de string do Python permitem que você transforme  o número em string, e substitua o caractere "." pela ",". 
Basta fazer algo como: `print(str(1234.56).replace(".", ","))`

### Abordagem correta: "locale"

No entanto embora essa técnica seja simples e funcione bem do ponto de vista do usuário final, não é considerada uma boa prática - por que semanticamente você não tem mais um número - está trocando caracteres numa string. O maior problema no entanto é que isso *amarra* o seu código numa formatação específica. Uma coisa é estar fazendo um pequeno programa de umas 300 linhas para uso pessoal. Outra é estar programando um sistema complexo, que terá que atender usuários em várias línguas e países diferentes, sempre "fazendo a coisa certa". E essa é a realidade tanto de quem codifica projetos Open Source, quanto de quem está em qualquer empresa que almeje crescer um pouco que seja.

Bom, claro que em tantas décadas de computação há formas padronizadas e corretas de se escrever um código genérico que possa formatar números (e escrever coisas como nomes de meses e dias da semana, ordenação de palavras com acento, etc...)  que funcionem para diversos países e línguas diferentes, bastando mudar a configuração. Essas formas atendem pelo nome de "locale" - e no Python são usáveis através do pacote de mesmo nome da biblioteca padrão: `locale`.

Para formatar números como usamos no Brasil você precisa dos seguintes passos:

- importar o pacote locale
- alterar a configuração de "locale" para números para usar português do Brasil com uma chamada a `locale.setlocale`
- converter seu número para string usando a função `locale.format`

Então, na verdade, se o programa vai ser fixo em português do Brasil, fica bem simples. Ah, para *ler* de volta um número digitado pelo usuário pode-se usar a função `locale.atof` para converter o número corretamente, de acordo com o país do programa.

Abaixo um pequeno programa que executa um print e um input usando o locale brasileiro (pt_BR) e o Americano (en_US) em sequência:

```
import locale


def body():
    suggestion = 3500
    str_value = input(
        "Digite a pretenção salarial (exemplo: R${}): ".format(
            locale.format("%.2f", suggestion)
        )
    )
    value = locale.atof(str_value)
    print(
        "Valor numérico interno: {}. Valor formatado: {}".format(
            value,
            locale.format("%.2f", value, grouping=True, monetary=True)
        )
    )


def main():
    for locale_name in ("pt_BR", "en_US"):
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, (locale_name, ""))
        print("\n\nExemplo usando o locale {}: \n".format(locale_name))
        body()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Alguns detalhes: as funções `locale.format` e `locale.format_string` usam a sintaxe de formatação numérica "antiga" do Python - a que usa o operador `%` para formatar strings - que herda do `printf` da linguagem C. Você pode consultar os detalhes dessa formatação na documentação, mas o importante é saber que você deve prover uma string de formatação começando com o caractere "%",  do tamanho total desejado do número, seguido de um "." seguido da quantidade de casas depois da vírgula desejadas e por fim o caractére "f" - ou seja, o nosso "%.02f" indica que vamos formatar um número decimal de um tamanho que nao importa, mas sempre com duas casas depois da vírgula.

Outro detalhe é que nesse exemplo usei o método "format" que era o recomentado para formatar strings nos últimos anos em Python - antes de sair o Python 3.6 - com Python 3.6 você pode usar as "fstrings" - strings em que as aspas são prefixadas com a letra "f" em vez de chamar o método "format" - e inserir expressões em Python diretamente entre chaves ({ }) dentro da própria string. A linha print final em Python 3.6 ficaria: `print(f"Valor numérico interno: {value}. Valor formatado: {locale.format("%.2f", value, grouping=True, monetary=True)}")`

Observe que o programa segue mais ou menos a boa prática de "ser tolerante com as entradas que recebe e ser estrito com o que imprime de volta" - não importa se o usuário digitar o separador dos milhares (o "." no caso dos números como usamos no Brasil) - ele formata de volta com esse separador, usando o parâmetro opcional "grouping" da função `locale.format`.

Veja a documentação completa do locale em https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html . E - para fins de deixar completa a resposta - se o programa for ser "internacionalizado" só o locale não é o suficiente - é necessário o uso de um framework que permita  a tradução de todas as strings que vão para a interface do programa. O módulo locale só cuida da formatação de números e nome de meses e dias da semana. Para traduções, é necessário o uso da biblioteca gettext: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html

Answer (score 2):

Desse jeito o novoNumeroficaria sem o ponto e com a virgula no lugar dele

```
 numero = input('Entre com o numero : ')
 novoNumero = numero.replace(".",",")
```

Comment: Vale lembrar que `raw_input` é uma função do **Python 2**, enquanto no Python 3 usa-se apenas `input`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim mas fiz só para efeito de exemplos, mas bom acrescento, irei editar