# Python - invalid literal for float()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Tenho uma array que está assim

```
training_set = [['03/11/2017' '16,94']
 ['01/11/2017' '16,90']
 ['31/10/2017' '16,77']
 ...
```

Porém, não consigo manipular os números por eles estarem em forma de *string*. Como faço pra limpar os dados e deixá-los assim

```
training_set = [['03/11/2017' 16,94]
 ['01/11/2017' 16,90]
 ['31/10/2017' 16,77]
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema está no formato do seu valor, como *string*. Você está utilizando a vírgula como separador decimal, mas o Python utiliza o ponto. Isto é, para converter para *float*, sua *string* deveria ser algo como `'16.94'`.

Você pode, antes de converter para *float*, tentar substituir a vírgula pelo ponto:

```
float('16,94'.replace(',', '.'))
```

Comment: Esse e o jeito "fácil e rápido". É bom para quem está aprendendo, etc -  para um sistema que vai ser internacionalizado, o correto  é usar locales - está detalhado na resposta desta questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221876/como-usar-v%C3%ADrgula-em-python-em-vez-de-ponto/222098#222098

Comment: Esse método usando replace, aparentemente, não funciona para arrays, funcinando apenas para números soltos. Recebi o erro (''numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'replace'')