# Analise de Dados com python

Tags: python

Eu tenho um arquivo cvs com duas colunas, uma de mes (Janeiro, fevereiro, etc) e outra com valor(relativo a cada mês), e quero criar um gráfico(de barras por exemplo), mas dá o seguinte erro: "TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot"

Arquivo:
[image: Arquivo]

Segue meu código (estou usando Jupyter):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

licitacoes = pd.read_csv("licitacoes.csv")

licitacoes.plot(kind='bar', x='Mes', y='valor')
plt.title('Valores por mes')
plt.xlabel('Mes')
plt.ylabel('valor')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Você poderia, por favor, colocar um trecho do arquivo para que nós possamos analisar? E se possível, uma parte maior do código, desde a leitura do conjunto de dados

Comment: Coloquei o resto do código e o arquivo

Answer (score 3):

Aparentemente o pandas não está reconhecendo a segunda coluna como dado numérico.

Supondo que o pandas deve reconhecer o "." (ponto) como separador decimal, ao invés da vírgula, talvez você só precise informar a formatação correta dos seus números ao fazer a importação.

Não sou um grande conhecedor de Pandas, mas na [documentação do método `read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) existe um parâmetro `decimalstr` que pode ser usado para configurar qual o caractere será usado como separador decimal.

> **decimalstr, default ‘.’**
>
> Character to recognize as decimal point (e.g. use ‘,’ for European data).

Teoricamente bastaria importar usando:

```
licitacoes = pd.read_csv("licitacoes.csv", decimalstr=",")
```

E o pandas reconheceria automaticamente como dados decimais.

Answer (score -1):

Tente isto antes de plotar novamente:

```
licitacoes.valor = licitacoes.valor.astype(float)
```

Edit:As variáveis da coluna 'valor' estão como strings, para plotar o gráfico você precisa de um valor numérico, ou seja, int ou float. O outro erro que aconteceu depois de tentar executar o código acima é devido ao Python não conseguir transformar o valor das strings em float, devido a linguagem usar o ponto para decimais. Para resolver o resto das questões sobre o uso de virgulas, recomendo olhar a pergunta que já foi feita neste fórum:
[https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221876/como-usar-vírgula-em-python-em-vez-de-ponto/222098#222098](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221876/como-usar-v%C3%ADrgula-em-python-em-vez-de-ponto/222098#222098)

Espero ter conseguido te ajudar em algo :)

Comment: Deu o seguinte erro: invalid literal for float(): 3235405819,22

Comment: O que acontece se você formatar o arquivo e trocar as vírgulas da coluna "valor" por pontos?