# Encontrar valores em blocos que se estendem por várias linhas

Tags: python, regex

Eu tenho um [Arquivo Espelho](https://pastebin.com/Pbw4mBzV) que contém espelhos de cupons, e criei um algoritimo para separar os cupons:

```
import re

txt = open("arqEspelho.txt", 'r+').read()

x = re.finditer(r".*COTIA\s*C*", txt)

z = re.finditer(r"OPR.*", txt)

espelhos = list(zip(x, z))

for espelho in espelhos:
    txt_espelho = txt[espelho[0].span()[0]: espelho[1].span()[1] + 1]
```

Esse `txt_espelho` seria o bloco do cupom ou seja o cupom separado, porém eu precisava separar ele por valor e extrato , tem uma linha que está exatamente assim:

```
<N>                     Extrato No. 042356</N>
```

Eu tentei encontrar desa forma:

```
re.findall(r'Extrato No. 042356', txt_espelho):
```

Porém ele ainda me retorna cupons aleatórios, também tem a linha de valor, que está assim:

```
TOTAL R$                                                717,30
```

E eu tentei encontrar ela assim:

```
re.findall(r"TOTAL\sR.*717,30", txt_espelho)
```

Porém ele se comporta como se não houvesse esse valor no `txt_espelho` sendo que tem
na variavel `x` eu defino o `inicio` do cupom , e na variavel `z` eu defino o `fim` do cupom.

Porém às vezes ele encontra a palavra "COTIA" em outros lugares do cupom, então eu tentei definir o início assim:

```
x = re.finditer(r".*CENTRO", txt)
```

Que se refere a palavra **centro que vem antes do cotia** para evitar erros, porém mesmo assim ele ainda não encontra  essa palavra.

Resumindo, eu preciso procurar o cupom **pelo valor e pelo extrato** nesses blocos de cupom.

---

Exemplo do arquivo:

```
                       COTIA CENTRO
                        ATACADAO S.A.
                      PROF JOSE BARRETO
--------------------------------------------------------------
CNPJ 75.315.333/0059-25
IE 278.157.726.114
IM ISENTO
--------------------------------------------------------------
<N>                     Extrato No. 042353</N>
<N>                CUPOM FISCAL ELETRÔNICO - SAT</N>
--------------------------------------------------------------
#|COD|DESC|QTD|UN|VL UN R$|(VL TR R$)*|VL ITEM R$
--------------------------------------------------------------
001 00025200 SAB.DOVE BRANCO         1X90G 
     1 UND9 X 2,39 (0,94)                                 2,39
002 00025200 SAB.DOVE BRANCO         1X90G 
     1 UND9 X 2,39 (0,94)                                 2,39
003 00061325 VINHO SANGUE BOI        1X1LT 
     1 UND9 X 11,90 (4,17)                               11,90
004 00004940 OLEO SOJA CONCORDIA   1X900ML 
     1 UND9 X 6,59 (0,74)                                 6,59
005 00048794 ESC.DENTAL DENTRAT A   1X1UND 
     1 UND9 X 2,25 (0,96)                                 2,25
006 00064376 HASTES FLEXIVEIS COT 1X150UND 
     1 UND9 X 2,29 (0,51)                                 2,29
007 00058824 SHAMP.DARLING         1X350ML 
     1 UND9 X 4,90 (2,20)                                 4,90
008 00004274 CAFE CABOCLO ALMOF.    1X500G 
     1 PCT8 X 6,88 (0,77)                                 6,88
009 00050143 REFR.PO TANG            1X25G 
     2 UND9 X 0,99 (0,48)                                 1,98
010 00050140 REFR.PO TANG            1X25G 
     1 UND9 X 0,99 (0,24)                                 0,99
011 00050144 REFR.PO TANG            1X25G 
     1 UND9 X 0,99 (0,24)                                 0,99
012 00050145 REFR.PO TANG            1X25G 
     1 UND9 X 0,99 (0,24)                                 0,99


Total bruto de Itens                                     44,54
<N>TOTAL R$                                                 44,54</N>


Dinheiro                                                 50,00

Troco R$                                                  5,46

--------------------------------------------------------------
OBSERVACOES DO CONTRIBUINTE


*Valor aproximado dos tributos do item
Valor aproximado dos tributos deste cupom
(conforme Lei Fed.12.741/2012) R$                        12,45
Vlr.Aprox.Tributos: Federal R$5,41 (12,15%) 
Vlr.Aprox.Tributos: Estadual R$7,04 (15,81%) 
Fonte: IBPT.
--------------------------------------------------------------
<N>                      SAT No. 000895390</N>
                    01/02/2021 - 07:30:50


<N>               3521 0275 3153 3300 5925 5900 </N>
<N>                  0895 3900 4235 3985 7588 </N>
CFe35210275315333005925590008953900423539857588|20210201073050|44.54||C7Vv8aEzrn2pHy6l0ldI4qbrPdlBfJ35VojuEoVTpblLmYZkerh7fZzDbLFIDdGc3ztTxM8ZaTWaF6veC3uKdy2A5a2ZiXhQZH62i3wn5PDR8rIPFGTJFmabD7GhkwOcNkPTGQKo/CW3x3ArPPjidX5cSl7O3yjWVKabD53OrAcn8HTLJsGSt/2hnHlf+RHcB9JEYC2IFQkOB9oWqlxifZUx+oUGtd3cTiad5ACHjexHh68xeYe+MPgNOECmaPPhaWq8/kgVAUZLsBnOdf3xefnU3+0NwBKujhZx3IsWbHRUFR1OPA8YFgcDGGwhJ0RtIw7wRi+dDtNNY31Cwa2o4A==
--------------------------------------------------------------
        TPLinux AT.14.c00X-18.06 - Unisys Brasil Ltda
--------------------------------------------------------------
EPSON TM-T20    VERSAO:10.02 ES    PDV:020    LJ:059
OPR:0008108Leidiana M                      01/02/2021 07:30:50
carro 



                        COTIA CENTRO
                        ATACADAO S.A.
                      PROF JOSE BARRETO
--------------------------------------------------------------
CNPJ 75.315.333/0059-25
IE 278.157.726.114
IM ISENTO
--------------------------------------------------------------
<N>                     Extrato No. 042354</N>
<N>                CUPOM FISCAL ELETRÔNICO - SAT</N>
--------------------------------------------------------------
#|COD|DESC|QTD|UN|VL UN R$|(VL TR R$)*|VL ITEM R$
--------------------------------------------------------------
001 00036102 COXA FGO SEARA IQF      1X1Kg 
     1 PCT9 X 8,98 (1,45)                                 8,98
002 00017122 ESC.D.SORRISO STD      1X1UND 
     1 UND9 X 2,35 (0,60)                                 2,35
003 00012075 CR.D.COLGATE MPA        1X90G 
     1 TBO9 X 2,14 (0,35)                                 2,14
004 00057464 SABAO PDC YPE COCO     1X200G 
     1 UND9 X 2,35 (0,52)                                 2,35
005 00033822 BISC.DUCHEN CR.CRACK   1X200G 
     1 UND8 X 1,49 (0,17)                                 1,49
006 00066640 MAC.PREDILLETO COMUM   1X500G 
     1 UND9 X 1,89 (0,21)                                 1,89
007 00066640 MAC.PREDILLETO COMUM   1X500G 
     1 UND9 X 1,89 (0,21)                                 1,89
008 00061018 SAB.PROTEX              1X85G 
     1 UND9 X 2,10 (0,47)                                 2,10


Total bruto de Itens                                     23,19
<N>TOTAL R$                                                 23,19</N>


Dinheiro                                                 24,00

Troco R$                                                  0,81

--------------------------------------------------------------
OBSERVACOES DO CONTRIBUINTE


*Valor aproximado dos tributos do item
Valor aproximado dos tributos deste cupom
(conforme Lei Fed.12.741/2012) R$                         3,98
Vlr.Aprox.Tributos: Federal R$1,20 (5,17%) 
Vlr.Aprox.Tributos: Estadual R$2,78 (11,99%) 
Fonte: IBPT.
--------------------------------------------------------------
<N>                      SAT No. 000895390</N>
                    01/02/2021 - 07:41:52


<N>               3521 0275 3153 3300 5925 5900 </N>
<N>                  0895 3900 4235 4685 9540 </N>
CFe35210275315333005925590008953900423546859540|20210201074152|23.19||cLWbQszXKX3f89kmOQ3k1Te72502OiJPKuqgKyehwiApqxvS3Jli1JVnjiCgXHHPZChueR8XXB61nurhmBJ3f/55Mphd4pq0UVjdMR61n+9/UPzq1MYCz2I3M2+/UTWw3aa3rzy+Y/bpUa6wOBn60+F/clO8jNc22AVzASdl62NH/rI2883hQfCxy53r/ECRtxDjujNHMjZcLbsBwAFeXbFANZcA3c7PECxcBxBtDP8lfuPqSPjjEbGL587KWEApILMLZwviqXUvYB6dkj5OC6iEwPpTuhRyZnHaZfSZzB3+n1qwCZVOKu8uKqHuw3gtcE3k6Q98tZ0O827+TbTMjQ==
--------------------------------------------------------------
        TPLinux AT.14.c00X-18.06 - Unisys Brasil Ltda
--------------------------------------------------------------
EPSON TM-T20    VERSAO:10.02 ES    PDV:020    LJ:059
OPR:0008108Leidiana M                      01/02/2021 07:41:52
carro 



                        COTIA CENTRO
                        ATACADAO S.A.
                      PROF JOSE BARRETO
--------------------------------------------------------------
CNPJ 75.315.333/0059-25
IE 278.157.726.114
IM ISENTO
--------------------------------------------------------------
<N>                     Extrato No. 042355</N>
<N>                CUPOM FISCAL ELETRÔNICO - SAT</N>
--------------------------------------------------------------
#|COD|DESC|QTD|UN|VL UN R$|(VL TR R$)*|VL ITEM R$
--------------------------------------------------------------
001 00009580 COXA/SOB.FGO MR FGO     1X1Kg 
 0,794 KG9  X 6,90 (0,89)                                 5,48
002 00009580 COXA/SOB.FGO MR FGO     1X1Kg 
 0,710 KG9  X 6,90 (0,79)                                 4,90
003 00009580 COXA/SOB.FGO MR FGO     1X1Kg 
 0,680 KG9  X 6,90 (0,76)                                 4,69
004 00009580 COXA/SOB.FGO MR FGO     1X1Kg 
 0,856 KG9  X 6,90 (0,96)                                 5,91
005 00009580 COXA/SOB.FGO MR FGO     1X1Kg 
 0,782 KG9  X 6,90 (0,87)                                 5,40
006 00009580 COXA/SOB.FGO MR FGO     1X1Kg 
 0,786 KG9  X 6,90 (0,88)                                 5,42
007 00009580 COXA/SOB.FGO MR FGO     1X1Kg 
 0,674 KG9  X 6,90 (0,75)                                 4,65
008 00009580 COXA/SOB.FGO MR FGO     1X1Kg 
 0,576 KG9  X 6,90 (0,64)                                 3,97
009 00009580 COXA/SOB.FGO MR FGO     1X1Kg 
 0,754 KG9  X 6,90 (0,84)                                 5,20
010 00033738 FRANGO CONFINA CONG.    1X1Kg 
 2,614 KG9  X 6,50 (2,75)                                16,99
011 00033738 FRANGO CONFINA CONG.    1X1Kg 
 2,568 KG9  X 6,50 (2,70)                                16,69
012 00033738 FRANGO CONFINA CONG.    1X1Kg 
 2,390 KG9  X 6,50 (2,52)                                15,54
013 00033738 FRANGO CONFINA CONG.    1X1Kg 
 2,564 KG9  X 6,50 (2,70)                                16,67
014 00033738 FRANGO CONFINA CONG.    1X1Kg 
 2,142 KG9  X 6,50 (2,26)                                13,92


Total bruto de Itens                                    125,43
<N>TOTAL R$                                                125,43</N>


Dinheiro                                                130,00

Troco R$                                                  4,57

--------------------------------------------------------------
OBSERVACOES DO CONTRIBUINTE


*Valor aproximado dos tributos do item
Valor aproximado dos tributos deste cupom
(conforme Lei Fed.12.741/2012) R$                        20,32
Vlr.Aprox.Tributos: Federal R$5,27 (4,20%) 
Vlr.Aprox.Tributos: Estadual R$15,05 (12,00%) 
Fonte: IBPT.
--------------------------------------------------------------
<N>                      SAT No. 000895390</N>
                    01/02/2021 - 07:44:32


<N>               3521 0275 3153 3300 5925 5900 </N>
<N>                  0895 3900 4235 5353 0841 </N>
CFe35210275315333005925590008953900423553530841|20210201074432|125.43||MMZY3pEVZjxz7vN1sCZoKgaOsMj8NqDgi3UFhuve6eSaIGstqJvtFd4Ho4jucoMxl2uJ9mTNOKzRpeuYpXOYwGJSqVzubhpNw63YmyGv8j3Yzi+HW+TXnJANrP+cPNCmCpcRYPvaxyLF/ko1JkwIUNGBN550pLsXcmCVqxXqgRR51VaspD72t4Rt8V+3ORuyJrVd07sSfnqj2jOlsYUg01M9czd7TGiddYJXC8BOR/427xYxVV1DAVKk019YXxEus3ZsKsTGDpQ4jycuTRv3DsS8OWUIVbh9Nhp5jBBijeRH7T46UyrcsJcRYfxTgS0WzhrqA3l8EBSDKdnOdeNUnQ==
--------------------------------------------------------------
        TPLinux AT.14.c00X-18.06 - Unisys Brasil Ltda
--------------------------------------------------------------
EPSON TM-T20    VERSAO:10.02 ES    PDV:020    LJ:059
OPR:0008108Leidiana M                      01/02/2021 07:44:33
carro
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que você está complicando à toa.

Em vez de sair varrendo a string procurando pelo início e fim de cada cupom, você pode simplesmente ir lendo linha a linha, e para cada linha você vê se está no início ou fim de um cupom, ou se tem um extrato, ou o valor total, etc.

Assim, você pode até usar regex para extrair as partes que interessam, mas fica mais simples:

```py
import re

re_extrato = re.compile(r'Extrato No. (\d+)')
re_total = re.compile(r'TOTAL R\$\s+(\d+,\d{2})')

cupons = [] # lista de cupons
with open("arqEspelho.txt", 'r') as arq:
    for linha in arq: # para cada linha do arquivo
        linha = linha.strip() # remove os espaços do início e fim, e as quebras de linha
        if linha == 'COTIA CENTRO': # início de um cupom
            # começa um novo cupom
            cupom = {}
        elif linha == 'carro': # final de um cupom
            cupons.append(cupom) # adiciona na lista de cupons
        else:
            # procura pelo extrato
            m = re_extrato.search(linha)
            if m: # se tem, seta o valor do extrato no cupom
                cupom['extrato'] = m.group(1)
            else: # senão, procura pelo total
                m = re_total.search(linha)
                if m: # se encontrou, pega o valor
                    cupom['total'] = m.group(1)
```

A partir do Python 3.8 você pode usar [*assignment expressions*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions), que deixa o código um pouco mais sucinto:

```
# A partir do Python 3.8
import re

re_extrato = re.compile(r'Extrato No. (\d+)')
re_total = re.compile(r'TOTAL R\$\s+(\d+,\d{2})')

cupons = []
with open("arqEspelho.txt", 'r') as arq:
    for linha in arq:
        linha = linha.strip() # remove os espaços do início e fim, e as quebras de linha
        if linha == 'COTIA CENTRO':
            # começa um novo cupom
            cupom = {}
        elif m := re_extrato.search(linha): # assignment expression, somente para Python >= 3.8
            cupom['extrato'] = m.group(1) # se achou o extrato, seta no cupom
        elif m := re_total.search(linha): # assignment expression, somente para Python >= 3.8
            cupom['total'] = m.group(1) # se achou o total, seta no cupom
        elif linha == 'carro': # final de um cupom
            cupons.append(cupom) # adiciona na lista de cupons
```

No caso, as regex possuem um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (os parênteses), que eu posso usar depois no método `group` para pegar somente a informação que eu quero (no caso, são os dígitos que correspondem ao extrato, ou o valor total).

O resultado será a lista `cupons`, na qual cada elemento é um dicionário contendo o valor do extrato e o total. Aí você pode usá-la para buscar os cupons usando o critério que quiser, por exemplo:

```
# buscar cupom pelo valor total
for cupom in cupons:
    if cupom['total'] == '44,54':
        print(f'achei, extrato={cupom["extrato"]}')
```

No caso, o total é uma string, mas você pode [converter para número](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/222098/112052) se quiser (acho que já foge do escopo da pergunta, mas enfim, uma vez tendo os dados, você pode manipulá-los como achar melhor).

E para extrair mais dados de cada cupom, basta colocar mais condições no `if`/`elif` e se for o caso, criar novas expressões para extrair o que precisa, e por fim guardar esses dados no dicionário `cupom`.

---

Ainda, se quiser todo o texto de cada cupom, basta ir incrementando-o no mesmo *loop*:

```
cupons = []
texto_cupom = ''
with open("arqEspelho.txt", 'r') as arq:
    for linha in arq:
        texto_cupom += linha # texto do cupom
        linha_sem_espacos = linha.strip() # remove os espaços do início e fim, e as quebras de linha
        if linha_sem_espacos == 'COTIA CENTRO':
            # começa um novo cupom
            texto_cupom = '' # começa um novo texto
            cupom = {}
        elif m := re_extrato.search(linha_sem_espacos):
            cupom['extrato'] = m.group(1)
        elif m := re_total.search(linha_sem_espacos):
            cupom['total'] = m.group(1)
        elif linha_sem_espacos == 'carro': # final de um cupom
            cupom['texto'] = texto_cupom # salva o texto todo
            cupons.append(cupom) # adiciona na lista de cupons
```

Ou seja, quando começa um cupom eu "zero" o texto, e quando termina, eu adiciono o texto atual no dicionário.

Comment: Muito obrigado , você é sensacional ;D