# Pegar números de uma string - python

Tags: python, regex

Como eu poderia pegar apenas os dígitos dessa string?

```
<SCANNER A7899739503929>
```

Já tentei usar o `findall`, mas sem sucesso ele me retorna vários números separados:

```
import re



txt = open("P:/portal/cupons/sco/sc_op.024_10_06.txt", "r+").read()


# usando finditer ele retorna a posição da palavra

    # Localiza o inicio do cupom
x = re.finditer(r"CAIXA.*", txt)
    # Localiza o fim do cupom
z = re.finditer(r"SUBTOTAL.*", txt)

espelhos = list(zip(x, z))

# Testando o valor específico para cada espelho
for espelho in espelhos:

    txt_espelho = txt[espelho[0].span()[0]: espelho[1].span()[1] + 1]

    print('===================================================================================================================================')

    codigos = re.findall(r"<SCANNER.*", txt_espelho)

    print(codigos)
```

Esses são os códigos separados:

```
<SCANNER A7891203021106>', '<SCANNER A7891203021106>', '<SCANNER A7891203021304>', '<SCANNER A7891203021304>', '<SCANNER A7891962036984>'
```

Como eu posso pegar apenas os números?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta trocar por:

```
re.findall(r"<SCANNER A(\d+)", txt_espelho)
```

No caso, `\d` é um atalho para "dígitos" e o quantificador `+` significa "um ou mais".

Já os parênteses criam um grupo de captura, e quando a regex tem grupos de captura, `findall` retorna somente eles. Assim, o retorno será uma lista contendo apenas os números que estão logo depois de `SCANNER A`.

A sua regex não funcionou porque você usou `.*`, e como o ponto pega qualquer caractere, pode acabar vindo caracteres que não são dígitos. Você até poderia usar apenas `findall(r'\d+', ...)`, mas aí retornaria números que não estão depois de `SCANNER A` (não sei se tem, se não tiver não fará diferença).

Por fim, eu acho que essa não é a melhor forma de tratar este arquivo (com várias regex varrendo tudo várias vezes). O melhor seria ler o arquivo linha a linha e processar os dados aos poucos, conforme forem encontrados, como sugerido [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/514258/112052).

Comment: Perfeito mano , porém a saida esta sendo varios cupons duplicados [link](https://pastebin.com/VmC1RwAz) , cada bloco de '===' equivale a um determinado cupom e estão saindo 3 de cada , você sabe o motivo ?

Comment: @INeedCoffe Sem ver o arquivo completo não dá pra adivinhar. Sugiro que abra [outra pergunta](/questions/ask), colocando alguns cupons de exemplo. Mas meu palpite é que o texto que vc passa deve ter mais de um cupom, não sei... Como eu já disse, não acho que essa seja a melhor solução, tente adaptar o código da resposta dada na [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/514258/112052), creio ser uma solução melhor...

Comment: Estou bloqueado de fazer perguntas :C , mas esse é o [link](https://pastebin.com/r8R1Ty0e) do arquivo , eu preciso pegar da palavra CAIXA ABERTO até a SUBTOTAL e entre isso pegar todos os codigos que estão dentro do <SCANNER> e separar tudo isso em blocos porém ta saindo tudo duplicado ;C

Answer (score 4):

De maneira simples voce pode fazer:

```
txt = '<SCANNER A7899739503929>'

somente_digitos = ''.join([d for d in txt if d.isdigit()])

print(somente_digitos)
'7899739503929'
```

Caso você possua uma lista

```
>>> lista = ['<SCANNER A7891203021106>', '<SCANNER A7891203021106>', '<SCANNER A7891203021304>', '<SCANNER A7891203021304>', '<SCANNER A7891962036984>']


>>> for item in lista:
...     print(''.join([d for d in item if d.isdigit()]))
...
7891203021106
7891203021106
7891203021304
7891203021304
7891962036984
```

Ou ainda, usar o map

```
>>> lista = ['<SCANNER A7891203021106>', '<SCANNER A7891203021106>', '<SCANNER A7891203021304>', '<SCANNER A7891203021304>', '<SCANNER A7891962036984>']

>>> print(list(map(lambda item: ''.join([d for d in item if d.isdigit()]), lista)))
['7891203021106', '7891203021106', '7891203021304', '7891203021304', '7891962036984']
```

Comment: Perfeito , porem estão vindo todos grudados , teria como separar a cada código ?

Comment: Sempre tem... acredito que a variável `codigos` seja uma lista de strings, correto? Sendo assim, use o último exemplo com `codigos` ao invés de `lista`

Answer (score 3):

O regex que você busca é `[0-9]+` que dá match nas partes do string que contém *pelo menos um ou mais dígitos*:

```
import re

entrada = "<SCANNER A7891203021106>, <SCANNER A7891203021106>, <SCANNER A7891203021304>, <SCANNER A7891203021304>', '<SCANNER A7891962036984>"
codigos = re.findall("[0-9]+", entrada)

print(codigos)
```

output:

```
['7891203021106',
 '7891203021106',
 '7891203021304',
 '7891203021304',
 '7891962036984']
```

Comment: A solução é boa para o caso apresentado, porém caso o termo tenha número e letras misturados, a solução não funcionará. Exemplo `<SCANNER A123B456C789D>`