# Pegar números com casas decimais de uma planilha xlsx e converter em horas no python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Este número 25,0555556, se formatado no Excel [h]:mm:ss, representa 601:20:00, como fazer com que o Python consiga ler em horas.
Trabalho com uma planilha que busca um relatório de um sistema e converte em planilha, e no momento de verificar como esta na planilha o valor fica em formato numérico, preciso fazer a formatação em horas. Agora estou passando esses dados da planilha para o Python e o valor fica formatado como número e com casas decimais.

[Acessar os arquivo para teste no Drive aqui](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13KT2LijqQ8d_yTld2z6-A4PEem2TmsbH?usp=sharing)

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. Clique no link [edit] e **coloque o código/erro como texto**. Veja mais sobre isso nesses links - [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774), [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774)

Comment: Ok, com não consigo descrever pelo fato de não conseguir manipular o arquivo, resolvi tirar a imagem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando se faz as contas, dá pra perceber que o número "25.05555556" que corresponde a "601:20" horas é expresso em dias.

A classe `datetime.timedelta` do Python pode aceita a entrada em dias, como float, e fazer as contas para segundos - automaticamente (ou você pode só fazer alguams divisões).  A partir do total de segundos é fácil obter as quantidades de horas, minutos e segundos usando o operador `//` para divisão inteira)

```
import datetime

period = datetime.timdelta(days=25.0555556)
hours = period.total_seconds() // 3600
minutes = (period.total_seconds() % 3600) // 60
seconds = (period.total_seconds() % 60) 

final = f"{hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}"
```

Se na sua leitura o "25..." está vindo como uma string
com uma "," no lugar de ".", a forma mais rápida é usar
o método `replace` da string pra trocar a `,` para `.` antes
de converter o valor pra numérico com `float` -
mas se for para um aplicativo que vai ficar em produção e pode
trabalhar arquivos formatados de outra forma, pode ser
mais interessante usar o módulo `locale` para
sempre fazer a substituição da forma correta - confira a resposta aqui: [Como usar vírgula em Python em vez de ponto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221876/como-usar-v%c3%adrgula-em-python-em-vez-de-ponto/222098#222098)

Comment: Funcionou, porém não consigo inserir o valor deste resultado obtido na variável final dentro de um dataframe. Quando repasso a informação o valor da coluna fica com 0:0 e não com o valor 601:20. rf['HT'] = final, o que mostra no dataframe é 0:0