# como imprimir dados tabulado em python?

Tags: python

Olá, queria saber se existe alguma forma de organizar melhor um arquivo .txt, pois estou gravando os dados e os espaçamentos estão todos errados, não esta da forma que o exercício pede. Reparem que a minha saída a coluna está toda desorganizada, assim como a coluna de porcentagens, existe alguma dica para deixar tudo bonitinho, com as colunas alinhadas dentro do arquivo .txt? [aqui está a saída do meu arquivo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wT0V4.png)

[essa é a forma que deveria sair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXg4s.png)

Aqui está o código, ele gera um controle de cota de disco, lendo um arquivo com o nome e a quantidade de bytes, depois gera um relatório com porcentagens e o uso da memoria em MB

```
def bytes_to_mb(l):
    j = 0
    total = 0
    while j < len(l):
        b = round(int(l[j][1])/1048576, 2)
        total += b
        l[j][1] = b
        j += 1
    return total


def percentual(total, l):
    j = 0
    while j < len(l):
        perc = (l[j][1] * 100)/total
        l[j].append(round(perc, 2))
        j += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cont = 0
    with open('usuarios.txt') as arq:
        lista = []
        for linha in arq:
            dados = linha.split()
            lista.append(dados)
        utilizado = bytes_to_mb(lista)
        percentual(utilizado, lista)
    with open('relatorio.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('ACME Inc.           Uso do espaço em disco pelos usuários\n')
        f.write('-----------------------------------------------------------\n')
        f.write('Nr.  Usuário        Espaço utilizado     % do uso\n')
        for i in range(0, len(lista)):
            f.write('{}    {}       {} MB             {}%\n'.format(i+1, lista[i][0], str(lista[i][1]), str(lista[i][2])))
            cont += 1
        f.write('\nEspaço total ocupado: {} MB\n'.format(utilizado))
        f.write('Espaço médio ocupado: {:.2f} MB'.format(utilizado/cont))
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Nesse código existe duas coisas que precisa ser adicionada por exemplo um alinhamento tabela e o separador das casas decimais que no Python padrão é `.`

Começando com o alinhamento de tabela com um exemplo:

```py
d = [ ["Mark", 12, 95],
     ["Jay", 11, 88],
     ["Jack", 14, 90]]
     
print ("{:<8} {:<15} {:<10}".format('Name','Age','Percent'))

for v in d:
    name, age, perc = v
    print ("{:<8} {:<15} {:<10}".format( name, age, perc))
```

Resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso você precisa definir limite de texto de cada campo usando `{:>n}` que é usado para alinhar para o lado direto,`{:<n}` para o lado esquerdo ou `{:^n}` para centralizar.

n = tamanho de limite do alinhamento.

Agora próxima fase é mudar o decimal separador que é algo bastante fácil que pode ser feito desse jeito:

```py
def CustomtoString(num):
    return '{0:.2f}'.format(num).replace('.', ',')
CustomtoString(2)
```

Resultado:

> 2,00

Essa foi a solução do código:

```py
def bytes_to_mb(l):
    j = 0
    total = 0
    while j < len(l):
        b = round(int(l[j][1])/1048576, 2)
        total += b
        l[j][1] = b
        j += 1
    return total

def MytoString(num):
    return '{0:.2f}'.format(num).replace('.', ',')

def percentual(total, l):
    j = 0
    while j < len(l):
        perc = (l[j][1] * 100)/total
        l[j].append(round(perc, 2))
        j += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cont = 0
    with open('usuarios.txt') as arq:
        lista = []
        for linha in arq:
            dados = linha.split()
            lista.append(dados)
        utilizado = bytes_to_mb(lista)
        percentual(utilizado, lista)
    with open('relatorio.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('ACME Inc.           Uso do espaço em disco pelos usuários\n')
        f.write('-----------------------------------------------------------\n')
        f.write('Nr.  Usuário        Espaço utilizado     % do uso\n')
        for i in range(0, len(lista)):
            f.write('{:<4} {:<14} {:>7} MB           {:>6}%\n'.format(i+1, lista[i][0], MytoString(lista[i][1]), MytoString(lista[i][2])))
            cont += 1
        f.write('\nEspaço total ocupado: {} MB\n'.format(utilizado))
        f.write('Espaço médio ocupado: {} MB'.format(MytoString(utilizado/cont)))
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais informações:

[Imprimir dados em formato tabular em Python](https://www.delftstack.com/pt/howto/python/data-in-table-format-python/)

[Formatação de número flutuantes](https://www.delftstack.com/pt/howto/python/python-format-float-to-string/#:%7E:text=Formate%20um%20n%C3%BAmero%20flutuante%20para%20uma%20largura%20fixa,ap%C3%B3s%20o%20ponto%20decimal%20no%20n%C3%BAmero%20de%20entrada.)

[Mudar o separador decimal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221876/como-usar-v%C3%ADrgula-em-python-em-vez-de-ponto)

Answer (score -3):

Para isso você pode usar a formatação do python e definir o espaço que o seu texto vai ocupar. Então, na linha de código:

```
f.write('{}    {}       {} MB             {}%\n'.format(i+1, lista[i][0], str(lista[i][1]), str(lista[i][2])))
```

você pode definir o espaço que cada variável vai ocupar na string e o alinhamento dela dentro desse espaço(esquerda, direita ou centro). Para fazer isso, dentro das chaves, colocamos o seguinte: ":alinhamento ('>' para alinhar a direita ou '<' para alinhar a esquerda ou '^' para alinhar ao centro) e o tamanho do espaço que o nosso texto vai ocupar. Exemplificando no código:

```
f.write('{:<5}{:<15}{:>7} MB{:>17}%\n'.format(i+1, lista[i][0], str(lista[i][1]), str(lista[i][2])))
```

Perceba que o primeiro item definimos para ocupar 5 espaços na string e ficar alinhado a esquerda, o segundo ocupa 15 espaços e fica alinhado a esquerda, o terceiro ocupa 7 espaços fica alinhado a direita, por fim o ultimo ocupa 17 espaços e fica alinhado a direita.
Se fizer isso, o texto fica alinhado como pede o exemplo.