# Formatação Numérica

Tags: python, formatação

Tenho uma lista com diversos valores financeiros e estou tentando formatar os números, porém não estou conseguindo.

Ex.: Tenho um valor 10535.30 e gostaria de transformar em R$ 10.535,30

Tentei chamar essa função, porém não funcionou:

```py
def formatar(valor):
    return "R${:,.2f}".format(valor)
```

Comment: Veja aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/222098/112052 - principalmente o exemplo no final: `locale.format("%.2f", value, grouping=True, monetary=True)`. E também pode usar `locale.currency`, veja na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html)

Comment: Caso seu programa usa uma lista com valores em moeda no formato de ponto flutuante você pode está com um problema ainda maior. Veja do que estou falando https://ideone.com/z6KvG1 exemplo baseado em [Por que números de ponto flutuante (Float e Double) são imprecisos?](https://ericlemes.com/2013/08/12/float/)

Answer (score 0):

Essa vírgula em `"R${:,.2f}"` na verdade serve para indicar que deseja separar os **milhares**.

Ex.: `format(100000, ",")` >> `"100,000"`.

- Você pode usar a opção `format(10_535.30, 'n')` que irá formatar para o padrão local.
- Ou então, criar uma função própria, separando os milhares e invertendo a pontuação:

```py
def formatar(valor):
    int_part, dec_part = format(valor, ',.2f').split('.')
    return f"R${int_part.replace(',', '.')},{dec_part}"

print(formatar(10_535.30))
```